# GAE Python app - Does URL matter for SEO?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, seo

I'm developing a web app right now with Google App Engine Python. It's a user generated content website and right now I let App Engine generate the unique numeric key for each entity (which is an individual page in my app). I then set this key as my permalink for each page so each permalink is for example: www.application.com/40394209.

My question is does this make a difference in terms of SEO? Would it be better to change the permalink to www.application.com/title-of-page? In which case I'd have to rewrite my app and manually set a custom string title as the key for each entity?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AFAIK the format of the link itself may matter for humans (for example getting hints about the link content just by hovering above it in the browser, without clicking on it), but doesn't really matter for SEO.

The page content (including metatags or attributes like description, title, canonical, etc) is what matters for SEO.

As an example, youtube links are not content-hinting, yet they're OK from SEO prospective:

- google search for `youtube cats cucumber`
- the 1st result points to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BRp7ezUqbI